# Rails 6: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker

OS: Manjaro

```
Webpacker can't find application.js in /run/media/wowvain/Software/Work/Ruby-on-Rails/blog/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
```

I've had this issue since I created the app with `rails new ...` but I managed to temporarily solve it by deleting the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` line in application.html.erb. While this managed to get my app running I believe javascript wasn't functional because when I tried deleting an entry from my db after scaffolding, it just redirected me to the edit page instead of getting the `Are you sure?` prompt. I found a workaround for that aswell by replacing `<%= link_to 'Destroy', friend, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-sm btn-link" %>` with `<%= button_to 'Destroy', friend, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-sm btn-link" %>` and it is able to destroy an entry without prompting me anything for confirmation. I tried to precompile the assets in order to generate a manifest file but I get this error: `error Command "webpack" not found` even though I ran `yarn add @rails/webpacker`  `yarn install` and `bundle update webpacker` (it just outputed I already have the latest version installed).

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.8'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: have you tried to install the webpack executable? what operating system are you using?

Comment: @wowvain please share the command you use to create the project and include the project `Gemfile` in your question

Comment: I'll add the Gemfile in a few but as for the OS im using Manjaro Linux. I don't think I tried installing the executable separately with 'yay -S webpack', should I? I think I created the project using RubyMine or simply 'rails new <projectname>'. I dont remember exactly which of the two.

Comment: I had this error many times from typos in style files, you should check if your application.js is also in the right folder

Comment: The thing is that I had this issue ever since I created the app, without any of my code in it so I don't think there should be any kind of typos.  The path to my application.js file is `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

Comment: @wowvain did you remember if `yarn install` ran or not

Comment: it did run. I believe I also accidentally ran `npm install` and that one worked aswell actually without any vulnerabilities.